# Javascript / JQuery: Record clicked elements to save them to MySQL-DB later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a small survey with two groups of buttons (Anker elements).
As the user makes his decision in group 1, group 2 will be shown and after the second decision, the values of the clicked buttons should be written to a MySQL database.

I have some problems with JavaScript respectively JQuery.

How can I protocol each clicked button from every group?

Under
https://jsfiddle.net/v2mtze2h/2/

you can find a small example.

I am aware of the fact, that in this state it cannot work, but I really don't know, how to differ between the two groups of buttons.

When I identify the first clicked button using

```
    firstclick = this.ad;
```

I cannot use

```
this.ad
```

for the second group.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Comment: First thing to consider is using unique `id` tags.

Comment: id's ahve to be unique. You reuse the id 1,2 and 3 in each list. Try using something like 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1,2-2 and 2-3 so you have unique ids, hence your logic doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an array to store the clicked id's as they are selected..

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/v2mtze2h/4/

```
var clickedControlsOrder = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#second").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        $("#first").addClass("hidden");
        clickedControlsOrder.push($(this).prop('id'));
        $('.info #info1').html(clickedControlsOrder.join(','));
    });
});
```

You can then change the array or store them by iterating through the array to store them in the table/database whatever way you want.

Comment: also - i changed your ID's slightly.. the comments on your question are correct - duplicate ID's are a big no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Can use data attributes and do something like setting group attribute on the parent container and an item number on each button

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $el = $(this), 
   group = $el.closest('[data-group]').data('group'),
   item = $el.data('item');
   console.log( 'Button:', group + '.'+ item)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="second" data-group="2">
  <span><a href="#" data-item="1">Button 2.1</a></span>
  <span><a href="#" data-item="2">Button 2.2</a></span>
  <span><a href="#" data-item="3">Button 2.3</a></span>
 </div>
```